# Gitlab runners waiting each other

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner

Good day, I have problem with runners, on same server but for different projects in gitlab, when runner a working, runner b waiting, what it can be?

Answer (score 0):

You can try in your `config.toml` file the `concurrent` param as described in the [gitlab docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-global-section), so that you can allow the execution of **multiple jobs in parallel** (across all your registered runners in your server).

> Concurrent :
> Limits how many jobs can run concurrently, across all registered runners. Each [[runners]] section can define its own limit, but this value sets a maximum for all of those values combined. For example, a value of 10 means no more than 10 jobs can run concurrently. 0 is forbidden. If you use this value, the runner process exits with a critical error.

So you can edit your `config.toml` with something similar to this :

```
concurrent = 4
check_interval = 0

# ... Your runners config...
```

Dont forget to restart you Gitlab Runner Service (or containers if you're using docker) to see the changes.

Comment: Ty, This setting also launches jobs in parallel in each stage, and here I have shell jobs lying around. Could this error be related to the fact that the executors of both runners are docker?

Comment: and recive  :The deployment job is older than the previously succeeded deployment job, and therefore cannot be run,  but previously jobs  fine  end

Comment: If you have multiple jobs in one stage you can work with the `needs` keyword that make relationships between jobs even in the same stage ( [doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#needs) ). This allows you to trigger a job from another project while ensuring that in your current project, only one job is executed, and the others remain in a pending state.